# Floating point precision problems when comparing to a RGN

Tags: c#, floating-accuracy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Floating point comparison functions for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874627/floating-point-comparison-functions-for-c-sharp)

I've read about all the problems with floating point precision and from what I've read the answer is in rounding. In my situation I have a double that has a value of .07 which actually stores as .070000000000000007. I need to compare .07 to a RGN between 0 and 1 that is also a double. The way I have resolved the problem is to round both numbers to 15 digits and then comapre them. Is this the correct way to do this?

Math.Round(RGN, 15) >= Math.Round(double, 15)

Thanks for the help!!

Gary

Comment: At minimum, `>=` won't do what you want.

Comment: Not exactly a duplicate in my opinion, but a good link - +1.