# .NET and beyond: best practices for using double arithmetic

Tags: c#, .net, math, double

I am developing a program which does some floating-point calculations, and I stumbled upon an interesting rounding issue in .NET, according to which expression:

```
0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3
```

evaluates to false, because:

```
0.1 + 0.2
```

evaluates to `0.30000000000000004`, and not `0.3`. That pretty severely affects unit testing.

I do understand why that happens, however what I'm interested to know is: what best practices should I be following when dealing with double arithmetic in order to avoid such problems where possible?

**EDIT**: using `decimal` type does not help

**SUMMARY**: I appreciate all for commenting. Unfortunately, some of you assumed that this question is how to make 0.1 + 0.2 to be equal 0.3, and that is not what I asked for. I accept that floating arithmetic can return value with variation. I was asking what common strategy is it a best practice to follow so that this variation does not cause issues. I think this question is ready to be closed.

Comment: If you expect `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` to evaluate to `true` use `decimal`.

Comment: Don't test for exact equality. Test to see if the result is within an acceptable error range, e.g. `Assert(Math.Abs((0.1 + 0.2) - (0.3)) < 1e-10)`

Comment: Also note if using `decimal` to use the correct suffix on literals: `0.1M + 0.2M == 0.3M`

Comment: The decimal type should allow for exact arithmetic and comparison in your example.

Comment: @GregS You miss the point. The calculation under test is performed using binary floating point. That's by design.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If the literals are decimals it works: `((0.1M+0.2M)==0.3M)` evaluates true

Comment: @ZoolWay Nobody (apart from MS) unit tests the built in addition operator for decimal operands. Are you saying you would write this exact code: `Assert.AreEqual(0.1m + 0.2m, 0.3m)`? Of course not. We are talking about code under test that performs binary floating point calculations.

Comment: @galets FWIW, this is not an issue of rounding, rather one of representability. None of the values you present, `0.1`, `0.2` and `0.3` can be exactly represented. So you are not adding `0.1` to `0.2`. You are adding the closest representable value to `0.1` to the closest representable value to `0.2`. And then rounding to the closest representable value. Which may not be the closest representable value to `0.3`. It's all about representability.

Comment: @ZoolWay decimals might work for the exact code in question, but that doesn't solve OP's general problem. `(1m/3m) * 3m == 1m` → `false`

Comment: @p.s.w.g Creating a infinite decimal number by divison is a very nice example against it, nice :) That can only be solved with tolerance.

Comment: @zool the equality would hold if we used ternary floating point. Remember that .net decimal is just base 10 floating point.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I have more trouble reading the minds of posters than you do. It was worth pointing out that decimal arithmetic can be done exactly. This would be appropriate for sums of money for example.

Comment: @GregS binary arithmetic can be done exactly, providing the values are representable. Decimal arithmetic is onlt exact for representable values. It's still inexact floating point. Just to base 10 rather than base 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You typically test for equality up to a certain tolerance.

So, in [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=equalityAsserts&r=2.2.6), for instance, you might write:

```
Assert.AreEqual(x, y, tol);
```

where `tol` is a suitably chosen tolerance value. Other unit testing frameworks will have similar assert functionality for floating point values.

Of course, how you choose the tolerance is, potentially, an enormous topic. Briefly, in order to know what tolerance to use, you need to know something about the calculation under test. Analysis of that calculation would be performed to decide on a suitable tolerance.

Answer (score 3):

Equality is calculated with some kind of episilon when using floating point types.

Compare to this answer: [Floating point comparison functions for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874627/floating-point-comparison-functions-for-c-sharp)

---

`Decimal` is an option but filling it must be done correctly: `decimal a = 0.1M`

`((0.1M+0.2M)==0.3M)` evaluates `true`!

Comment: Decimal is not an option when the code under test uses binary floating point.

Comment: Yes, it is true that decimal is not an option when the values you have got already are floating points. But that is not in the question, just best-practise for how to handle floating comparison. Best practise is an epsilon/tolerance-comparison - or when possible use a not-so-floating type ;)

Comment: Yes that really is the question. The question is about comparing binary floating point values.

Comment: Reading the title - point taken!

Answer (score 1):

Two things you need to read:

- [*What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic, or Why don’t my numbers add up?*](http://floating-point-gui.de/)
- David Goldberg's most excellent 1991 paper, [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Arithmetic*](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=103162.103163&coll=DL&dl=GUIDE&CFID=292212361&CFTOKEN=51068098) [GOLDBERG91]. Here's the abstract:

  > Floating-point arithmetic is considered as esoteric subject by many people.
  >   This is rather surprising, because floating-point is ubiquitous in computer systems:
  >   Almost every language has a floating-point datatype; computers from PCs to
  >   supercomputers have floating-point accelerators; most compilers will be called upon
  >   to compile floating-point algorithms from time to time; and virtually every
  >   operating system must respond to floating-point exceptions such as overflow.
  >   This paper presents a tutorial on the aspects of floating-point that have a direct
  >   impact on designers of computer systems. It begins with background on floating-point
  >   representation and rounding error, continues with a discussion of the IEEE floating
  >   point standard, and concludes with examples of how computer system builders can
  >   better support floating point.

  And a couple of source of the paper in PDF form:

  - http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/jean-michel.muller/goldberg.pdf
  - https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf

  And if you're a member of the ACM, you can [download it from the ACM's *Digital Library*](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=103162.103163&coll=DL&dl=GUIDE&CFID=292212361&CFTOKEN=51068098).

And don't forget this treasure trove of ruefully acquired floating point wisdom: http://randomascii.wordpress.com/category/floating-point/

[GOLDBERG91]
Goldberg, David, 1991. "A simple but realistic model of floating-point computation." *ACM Computing Surveys*, vol. 23, no. 1, March 1991. pp. 5-48.

Comment: Goldberg's paper is freely available in html form. Just search for the title. It's the top hit.

Comment: I prefer PDF as it's easier to read and prints better.