# Two Arrays have same values but do not returns equal

Tags: c#, arrays, compare

I want to compare two arrays and if all the values are the same i will do some stuff. I write a function like this to check is there any different value. If so return false.

```
bool Deneme () 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < correctOnes.Length; i++) {

        if(correctOnes[i] != cubeRotation[i].rotation.eulerAngles) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I call the Deneme function it always return false. However, I check the array values in the console they are all same. Any ideas what is going on ?

Checking the console like that

```
    for (int i = 0; i < correctOnes.Length; i++) {

        Debug.Log ("Corrects: " + correctOnes[i]);  
        Debug.Log ("Cubes: "  + cubeRotation[i].rotation.eulerAngles);  

    }
```

Console Photo:
[image]

Comment: If they are equal, why aren't you using Array.Equals()?

Comment: @cFrozenDeath: For two reasons; because it's an array of values that is compared to properties in an array of objects, and because `Array.Equals` compares the references not the array values.

Comment: What is the type of the values that you compare?

Comment: Vector3 I both try float but result is same

Comment: Are you sure you're comparing the right values in the debugger? Your code seems correct at a glance - put a breakpoint on the `return false;` statement and check the value of `i`. Is it index 0? Is it at the end of the array?

Comment: Yes i am sure indexs are correct. I edit the question show the console message

Comment: What namespace is Vector3 in? Does it implement IComparable? I would breakpoint and inspect all elements of the arrays manually, or add some Debug.WriteLine(...) to help clarify.

Comment: I don't believe you. Post your debug logs.

Comment: hahah @choz you are funny.  I do not implement IComparable. I have only one single scripts so no need to put them namespace.

Comment: If you are using the Vector3 I think you are using, the components will be floats. http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.html
Float comparisons are well known for being troublesome. You generally want to include some sort of 'tolerance'.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874627/floating-point-comparison-functions-for-c-sharp

Comment: You're being backed by floating point?  Then there are problems with comparing equals.  [If you're doing any sort of calculation on the number, your expected result may not (and often won't) match the calculated result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken).

Comment: Quite probably, this is because of a precision error. Printed might look the same but, when compared, they differ by some (very small) value.

Comment: Convert all the values to int and see the differences. Very helpfull comments. Thak you so much.

Comment: That's how the logs help, I missed everything :(

Comment: Unity is best come back. :D @choz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a try with

```
bool Deneme () 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < correctOnes.Length; i++) {

        if (!Mathf.Approximately (correctOnes[i].magnitude, cubeRotation[i].rotation.eulerAngles.magnitude))     
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The most likely reason for this is that `eulerAngles` is `double`, which means that it should not be compared with operator `==`. Two numbers may look the same when printed, but they would compare as non-equal.

The trick here is to compare using `Math.Abs(a-b) < 1E-8` method:

```
if(Math.Abs(correctOnes[i]-cubeRotation[i].rotation.eulerAngles) < 1E-8) {
    ...
}
```

Above, `1E-8` is a small number that represents the tolerance for comparing `double`s for equality.

Comment: Are you sure `Double.Epsilon` is the right constant? That is the smallest positive number that can be represented in a `double`. Correct me if I'm wrong but this check is esentially the same as using `==`. I think some larger (but still small) epsilon should be used, like `1e-8`

Comment: this doesnt work for me. double.eplision i think something around 4.

Comment: @ÇağatayKaya I think epsilon is too small for your purposes. Try `1E-8` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I posted the test scaffolding for completeness, but the linq query at line #35 should get you your pass/fail results.

```
class Ans34467714
{
    List<double> correctOnes = new List<double>() { 22.7, 22.6, 44.5, 44.5, 44.5};
    List<rotation> cubeRotation = new List<rotation>() { new rotation() { eulerAngles = 22.3 }, new rotation() { eulerAngles = 22.6 }, new rotation() { eulerAngles = 44.5 }, new rotation() { eulerAngles = 44.5 }, new rotation() { eulerAngles = 44.5 } };

    public Ans34467714()
    {

    }

    internal bool Execute(string[] args)
    {
        bool retValue = false;
        if (Deneme())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Pass");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fail");
        }

        return retValue;
    }
    internal bool Deneme()
    {
        return correctOnes.Where((var, index) => cubeRotation[index].eulerAngles == var).Count() == correctOnes.Count;
    }
}
class rotation
{
    public double eulerAngles {get; set;}
    public rotation()
    {

    }

}
```