# C# accuracy when checking float in List<float> with Contains method

Tags: c#, list, contains, floating-accuracy

I have a list of `float`s and want to check if it already contains a particular value with the `List.Contains()` method. I know that for `float` equality tests you often can't use `==` but something like `myFloat - value < 0.001`.

My question is, does the `Contains` method account for this or I do I need to use a method that accounts for `float` precision errors for testing if the float is in the list?

Comment: Did you try it? Any issues met?

Comment: the `Contains` only does the simpliest comparison. it doesn't handle that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874627/floating-point-comparison-functions-for-c-sharp

Comment: how about `myList.Any(f=>Math.Abs(f-value)<0.0001)`

Comment: You actually can use == perfectly well with floats, you just need to know what that means...

Comment: @CoryNelson I strongly recommend reading http://twistedoakstudios.com/blog/Post3044_my-bug-my-bad-2-sunk-by-float  before assuming == is safe with floats.  Specifically the part titled "Wrong #3".

Comment: @BryceWagner thanks, that'll be useful to someone here. But my comment stands. Float comparison has become the new "never use goto".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the docs for [`List(T).Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx):

> This method determines equality by using the default equality comparer, as defined by the object's implementation of the [`IEquatable<T>.Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131190(v=vs.110).aspx) method for T (the type of values in the list).

So you will need to handle comparison with a threshold yourself. For example, you can use your own custom equality comparer. Something like this:

```
public class FloatThresholdComparer : IEqualityComparer<float>
{
    private readonly float _threshold;
    public FloatThresholdComparer(float threshold)
    {
        _threshold = threshold;
    }

    public bool Equals(float x, float y)
    {
        return Math.Abs(x-y) < _threshold;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(float f)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Unable to generate a hash code for thresholds, do not use this for grouping");
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
var result = floatList.Contains(100f, new FloatThresholdComparer(0.01f))
```

Answer (score 2):

It just uses the default equality comparison for objects contained in the list. It will be the equivalent of calling `object.Equals()` when performing the comparisons.

If you need a different equality implementation, you could use the linq [`Contains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118(v=vs.110).aspx) overload that accepts an equality comparer.  Then you'd just have to implement that comparison and pass it in.  This should perform roughly the same but ultimately slower.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct, but if you want an alternative quick-and-dirty solution without writing a new equality comparer, you could use the List.Exists Method:

```
bool found = list.Exists(num => Math.Abs(num - valueToFind) < 0.001);
```

**Edit**:
    My original answer said the above was Linq, however the Exists method is part of the List class.  The same concept using Linq is below, using IEnumerable.Any:

```
bool found = list.Any(num => Math.Abs(num - valueToFind) < 0.001);
```

Comment: I like that - that's a clever application of LINQ