# An expression in an if statement returns true but the if statement dont do what is in it

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-2.0, floating

I use unity and visual studio 2017 for debugging and editing my unity code and i created a bool function, but when it returns true the if statement will not do what is inside :-

My Function:-

```
private bool EnemyClosed(float enemyv, float playerv)
{
    for(float i = -0.9f; i<=0.9f; i+=0.1f)
        if (enemyv == (playerv + i))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

The error is in there `if (enemyv == (playerv + i)) return true;` i debugged the code while the `enemyv` equals to `(playerv + i)` but it wont return true and i dont know why, is there any error please?

Edit :-

I know i can't compare floats using equals sign but when i compare them using `Mathf.Approximately` function it needs some time to find the result, i saw this while i was debugging my program and i used immediate window to find their equality using above function allways it spent some time to find the result so i don't want to use `Mathf.Approximately` function so please help me to find some easy code to compare them.

Comment: Are you sure that they're actually equal? When you're debugging at the point where it should return true, use the immediate window to run `enemyv == (playerv + i)`.

Comment: `==` doesn´t work well together with floating-point numbers, as those cannot be stored properly into the memory. To avoid this you should allways introduce some small buffer, e.g. by using `Math.Abs`.

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-sharp-imprecise)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874627/floating-point-comparison-functions-for-c-sharp

Comment: I always use {} after for and if statements to make them easier to read. I suspect @HimBromBeere has hit on the issue

Comment: Don't check equality on float (they are always approximated), use a range if you really have to use floats, or just switch to integers and "return" to float only at end of calculation, in your case yu can do: `int pv = playerv * 10; for (int i=-9; i<9; ++i) /*then check against integers*/`

Comment: This question is not duplicate but the answer of @DDS is right because i tried at the immediate window the two floats were `-3.7` and `-3.7` and when i wrote `==` for them it sais false but when i wrote approximately the output changes to true, so thank you all guys you fixed my problem.

Comment: Why dont you do : `public static bool EnemyClosed(float enemyv, float playerv)
    {
        for (float i = -0.9f; i <= 0.9f; i += 0.1f)
            playerv = playerv + i;
            if (enemyv == playerv)
                return true;
        return false;
    `