# rigidbodycomponent.velocity.y = 0 apparently causes a bug (making pong)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was testing out scripts and there was a bug, that output 0 as its `Rigidbody.velocity.y` only if it goes up (so when the random chance it goes down it doesn't break), until it becomes negative (collision with resitution 1 or mirror bouncy) which then output a nonzero integer, so working as normal.
Edit: The temporary solution is just to remove the if statement in  `if (rb.velocity.y != 0)` but i wanna know why does it output 0
Edit2: Maybe its a Unity bug, and i am in Unity 2019.4, so updating might be the solution? So if the "bug" dissapears, im sorry for wasting your time

First code determines the ball, while the second determines the ai

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BallMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Vector3 startPosition;
    public float rampSpeed;
    private float startSpeed;
    public float tempSpeed;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        startPosition = transform.position;
        startSpeed = speed;
        Launch();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    private void Launch()
    {
        float x = Random.Range(0,2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;
        float y = Random.Range(0,2) == 0 ? -1 : 1;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(speed * x, speed * y);
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D ()
    {
        tempSpeed = speed;
        speed += rampSpeed;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x*speed/tempSpeed,rb.velocity.y*speed/tempSpeed);
        GetComponent<AudioBall>().SoundCollision();
    }
    public void Reset()
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        transform.position = startPosition;
        speed = startSpeed;
        Launch();
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isPlayer1;
    public float speed;
    public float moveInput;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    public Vector3 startPosition;
    //AI
    [Header("Ball")]
    public GameObject ball;
    private Rigidbody2D rbBall;
    private float sign;
    public bool ActivateAI;
    public bool TurnOnOveride;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (TurnOnOveride == false)
        {
            ActivateAI = PlayMenu.ActivateAI;
        }
        else
        {
            ActivateAI = true;
        }
        startPosition = transform.position;
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(ActivateAI == false || isPlayer1 == true)
        {
            //this part is just human control. dont mind this
            if (isPlayer1 == true)
            {
                moveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
            }
            else
            {
                moveInput = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical2");
            }
        }
        //AI
        else
        {
            rbBall = ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            sign = Mathf.Sign(rbBall.velocity.y);
            Debug.Log("sign:"+sign);
            if (sign == -1)
            {
                moveInput = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("rb.y:"+rb.velocity.y);
                if (rb.velocity.y != 0)
                {
                    moveInput = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, moveInput * speed);
    }
    public void Reset()
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector2.zero;
        transform.position = startPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which one logs `0`, the `sign` or the `rb.velocity.y`? One would expect both I guess

Comment: sign is 1, meanwhile rb.velocity.y is 0, sign apprently doesnt make 0 inputs to just result 1 :/

Comment: I guess your velocity is something like `0.0001` so the log crops it down to `0` while it is not really exactly `0`. Also the check for `!= 0` or `==0` is dangerous for float values .. see [Flaoting point comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874627/floating-point-comparison-functions-for-c-sharp)

Comment: oh right yeah i should watch out for ==  or != 0 statements, but i can see the ball game object, move up = to its horizontal speed, but managing to be 0, its multiplied by a speed variable (5 is the base), so there is no way its +/- 0.000000something

Comment: @Shade to your latest question, installing a newer major .NET runtime replaces the older one. A newer .NET 4.x runtime replaces any older version. Same for .NET Core 2.x, 3.x, 5.x. Only major versions can be installed side-by-side.