# Validating an integer value against float in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, c#-4.0

I have a textbox where the user can enter a double point number . For eg:-

```
1.00
1.0000
1.23
1.000000
```

etc , the double numbers from the UI can be entered.

In my C# code I have to validate if the user has entered 1 or not.

```
1.00
1.0000
1.000000
```

are all considered as 1 and pass the validation .
I was thinking of converting to Int

```
public bool Validate(double number)
{
  int v = Convert.ToInt32(number)
  if(v == 1)
   return true;
}
```

But the problem is I will lose precision , both 1.00 and 1.001 will result as 1 and incorrectly 1.001 will be returned as true which I dont need.
How to check if the user has entered 1.00,1.000,...etc from UI in C#?

Edit :
I dont need true for numbers like 1.23, 1.001 etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Floating point comparison functions for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3874627/floating-point-comparison-functions-for-c-sharp)

Comment: I must be missing something - why not just `return (number == 1)`?

Comment: Note that user can still type something like "1.0000000000000001" and it will be equal to 1 no matter what, because it will parse (with `double.Parse`) as 1 (double doesn't have precision to represent such value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `decimal` data type

```
public bool Validate(double number)
{
    var num = decimal.Parse(number.ToString());
    if(num == 1)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Will it return "true" for `1.23`? =)

Comment: No. It will return true only for 1.0, 1.00000, 1.0000000000 or 1

Comment: OP needs it to be true for `1.23`

Comment: @GuruStron : No. I dont need true for 1.23

Comment: What's the point to convert double to decimal, though a string, for that?

Comment: @VA1267 that what your question states -  _" eg:- 1.00
1.0000
1.23
1.000000
are all valid."_ I clearly see `1.23` there

Comment: @GuruStron : It is valid from UI perspective , they can enter any decimal value . Ok let me edit the question as well to make it clear

Answer (score 4):

Comparing the value to 1.0 should do the trick:

```
bool isOne = val == 1.0;
```

(Equality comparison of floating-point numbers can be tricky, but this one works the way you'd expect.)

Edit: Using `1` instead of `1.0` also works, as Matthew Watson suggested in the comments.