# Why is the velocity not zero even though the object is not moving

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm making a procedural walk animation and I need to check if the player is moving or not and the direction the player is moving. And Im using a rigidbody to move my player.

So I checked the value of its velocity and printed it out and it gave me **4.065124E-18** when the player was not moving

here is my player controller code. I uses the new input system.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;


public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float speed, maxForce;
    private Vector2 move;
    [SerializeField] IKFootSolver leftfootSolver;
    [SerializeField] IKFootSolver rightfootSolver;

    public void OnMove(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        move = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    }
    
     private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Find target velocity
        Vector3 targetVelocity = new Vector3(move.x, 0, move.y);
        
        Vector3 MoveVector = transform.TransformDirection(targetVelocity) * speed;
        rb.velocity = new Vector3(MoveVector.x, rb.velocity.y, MoveVector.z);


        if (targetVelocity == Vector3.zero)
        {
            leftfootSolver.moving = false;
            rightfootSolver.moving = false;
        }
        else
        {
           
                leftfootSolver.moving = true;
                rightfootSolver.moving = true;
            
        }
    }
// Start is called before the first frame update
    // Update is called once per frame
  
}
```

And here is my procedural walk code

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    transform.position = currentPosition;
    transform.up = currentNormal;

    Ray ray = new Ray(body.position + (body.right * footSpacing), Vector3.down);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit info, 10, terrainLayer.value))
    {
        var localVelocity = transform.InverseTransformDirection(PlayerRB.velocity);
        Debug.Log(localVelocity.z);
        if (moving) {
            
            if (localVelocity.z > 0)
                {
                
                if (Vector3.Distance(newPosition, info.point) > stepDistance && !otherFoot.IsMoving() && lerp >= 1)
                {
                    //Debug.Log(lerp);
                    stopped = false;
                    lerp = 0;
                    int direction = body.InverseTransformPoint(info.point).z > body.InverseTransformPoint(newPosition).z ? 1 : -1;
                    newPosition = info.point + (body.forward * stepLength * direction) + footOffset;
                    newNormal = info.normal;
                }
            }
        }
        
        else if (moving ==false && lerp >= 1 && stopped == false && !otherFoot.IsMoving())
        {
            Debug.Log(lerp);
            if (oldPosition != info.point)
            {
                
                lerp = 0;
                newNormal = info.normal;
                newPosition = info.point;
                
            }
            stopped = true;

        }
    }

    
}
```

here's the issue part

```
var localVelocity = transform.InverseTransformDirection(PlayerRB.velocity);
Debug.Log(localVelocity.z);
if (moving) {
            
   if (localVelocity.z > 0)
    {}
}
```

Comment: I guess that's because floating point arithmetic is always just an approximation. Instead of checking against `> 0.0` try to check against a value slightly above zero that you would still consider "not really moving", e.g. `> 0.001`.

Comment: The 'E' in " 4.065124E-18" is a scientific notation. this number is incredibly close to 0. 0.000000000000000004065124 to be exact ;) I would suggest to instead checking for 0 check for 0.01 >

Comment: From the duplicate see in specific [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67936871/7111561)