# Creating a method returning a boolean taking an object as argument

Tags: java

Can anyone help me. i want to compare if two cars are faster by a method `isFaster(Car otherCar)`. Can someone help me understand how the `Car` object is compared with the `otherCar` object which is an argument on the `isFaster` method. How can I go about creating the body of the method.

```
public class Car {
  private String make ="";
  private int year = 0;
  private int maxSpeed = 0;

  public Car(String make,int year,int maxSpeed){
    this.make = make;
    this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
    this.year = year;
  }

  public void setSpeed(int maxSpeed){
    this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
  }

  public void setMake(String make){
    this.make = make;
  }

  public void setYear(int year){
    this.year = year;
  }

  public int getMaxSpeed(){
    return maxSpeed;
  }

  public int getYear(){
    return year;
  }

  public String getMake(){
    return make;
  }

  public String toString(double param){
    String temp = String.valueOf(param);
    return temp;
  }

  public String toString(int param){
    String temp = String.valueOf(param);
    return temp;
  }

  public String toString(char param){
    String temp = String.valueOf(param);
    return temp;
  }
}
```

Comment: Show us the `Car` class. And... have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Show is what you've tried.

Comment: Presumably your problem isn't writing a car comparison program but something more fundamental (such as calling a field of an object). You'll get a more helpful response if you ask about the fundamental problem.

Comment: Tip taken will make sure to do so next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a method like this

```
public boolean isFaster(Car anotherCar){
   return this.maxSpeed > anotherCar.maxSpeed;
}
```

In a client code example:

```
public static void main(String args []){
  Car car1 = new Car();
  car1.setSpeed(200);// should be setMaxSpeed();
  Car car2 = new Car();
  car2.setSpeed(250);

  System.out.println(car1.isFaster(car2));// prints false

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the Car object, there must be some attributes with it, say

```
class Car{

    int gear;
    double speed;
}
```

When you need to compare, you need to decide, on the deciding attribute to compare.

If its speed then

```
// isFaster will only return true if the calling car object is faster 
// than the otherCar

// for your class this should work

isFaster(Car otherCar){       
    return this.getMaxSpeed() - otherCar.getMaxSpeed()  ;
}

// If you use double for speed, and you need precision
// you can set some tolerance value for comparisons.

isFaster(Car otherCar){       
    return (this.getMaxSpeed() - otherCar.getMaxSpeed() ) < TOLERANCE ;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: May I suggest: `return this.speed > otherCar.speed;`

Comment: @pamphlet it is not good to compare `double`s like that: http://stackoverflow.com/q/434657/1065197 http://stackoverflow.com/q/11390853/1065197

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I agree, but I was just advising against the if-true-return-true-else-return-false anti-pattern.

Comment: @pamphlet Edited it for taking tolerance into consideration. Also I had that if else true false format to help OP understand it better.

Comment: Assuming that the speed is directly input in the constructor rather than calculated at some point a double comparison aught to be safe even on the "fine" boundary, surely?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the `Car` class has a method such as `double getMaxSpeed ()`, you could implement the `isFaster (Car otherCar)` as follows:

```
boolean isFaster (Car otherCar) {
    return this.getMaxSpeed() > otherCar.getMaxSpeed ();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to override **.equals()** method based on speed then only you can compare your objects meaningfully. otherwise by default **.equals()** uses **==** to compare objects in this case objects can be equal only if they are same

Comment: So you're saying two cars are the same car if they are travelling at the same speed?